Solve for integers $x,y,$ $5^x - 277y = 55$
I'm working with the equation $5^x - 277y = 55$ and I'm trying to:
Determine if there are any integer solutions
Understand the relationship between x and y

So far, I've tried:
Rearranging to 5^x = 277y + 55
Looking for small integer values of x to see if the right side divides evenly by 277

I'm stuck because:
I'm not sure if this requires a specific technique
I don't know if I should be using logarithms here
The presence of both exponential and linear terms is confusing me

Can someone help explain how to approach this type of equation?

$(x,y)=(8,1410)$

$277$ is prime and $5$ is a primitive root, so $x=276n+8\iff 5^x\equiv5^8\equiv55\bmod277$

Yes, $5^8\equiv 55\pmod {277},$ so you know $x\equiv 8\pmod{o_{277}(5)}$ is necessary and sufficient for $y $ to exist.

First we note that $277$ is a prime. Let $a=o_{277}(5)$, namely the smallest positive integer such that $5^a \equiv 1 \pmod{277}$. Using Fermat Little theorem, it is immediate that
$$5^{276} \equiv 1 \pmod{277}$$
so the order $a$ must be a divisor of $276$. We have the factorization
$$ 276 = 2^2 \times 3 \times 23$$
By inspection, you can see that $$\begin{cases}5^{138} \equiv -1 \pmod{277}\\
5^{92} \equiv 116 \pmod{277}\\
5^{12} \equiv 27 \pmod {277},\end{cases},$$
so $a = 276$, otherwise $a$ must be a divisor of either $138,92$ or $12$, which is absurd.
Now if for $a \ge b \ge 0$ $$5^a \equiv 5^b\equiv 55 \pmod{277}, $$ we have $5^{a-b} \equiv 1 \pmod{277}$, which implies $276 \mid a-b$. So if you could find some $a_0$ such that $5^{a_0} \equiv 55 \pmod{277}$, the other solutions $x$ must satisfy $x \equiv a_0 \pmod{276}$. By inspection again, we found $a_0=8$ is an integer satisfying $5^{a_0}-55$ is divisible by $277$, so $x = 276k+8$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$. The number $y$ will be presented in term of $x$.

Sage code: You can run this at https://sagecell.sagemath.org to find a small root, namely $a_0=8$ as mentioned above

for i in range(277):
 if (5^i-55)%277 == 0:
     print(i)


You have to rule out other possible orders of $5$ such as $92$

@J.W.Tanner Oh Yes, thank for mentioning that, I checked all of them but somehow when writing this, I falsely thought it is enough to check $138$, will edit right away.

This is not unlike the other posted answer, but I do some cleanup first to help me think. Note there is no solution with $x=0$. We then have that $y$ must be divisible by $5$, so the equation is equivalent to solving: $$5^a-277b=11$$
Mod $4$, $b\equiv2$. So $b=4c+2$, and: $$5^a-1108c=565$$
Note again that there is no solution with $a=0$. Now $c$ must be divisible by $5$, so the equation is equivalent to: $$5^d-1108e=113$$
Again, there is no solution with $d=0$. We look mod $5$ and find $e\equiv4$, and so $e=5f+4$:
$$\begin{align}
5^d-5540f
&=4545\\
5^g-1108f&=909
\end{align}$$
Again, there is no solution with $g=0$. And again examining mod $5$, we find $f=5h+2$: $$5^g-5540h=3125$$
This is finally something special because the right side is a power of $5$:
$$\begin{align}
5^g-5540h=5^5\\
5^k-1108h=5^4\\
5^k-5^4=1108h
\end{align}$$
Note there are no solutions for $k<4$. So now $h$ is divisible by $5^4$, so we have: $$5^m-1=1108n$$ This equation is always true mod $4$. Let's consider it mod $277$. Of course periodically, we will have $5^m\equiv_{277}1$. And then $5^m-1$ will be divisible by $1108$. The order of $5$ is some divisor of $276=4\cdot3\cdot23$. You can check $5^{276/2}\not\equiv_{277}1$, so $4$ divides the order of $\varphi$. And $5^{276/3}\not\equiv_{277}1$, so $3$ divides the order of $\varphi$. And $5^{276/23}\not\equiv_{277}1$, so $23$ divides the order of $\varphi$. All told, the order is the full $276$.
So $m=276p$ will give a solution. Backtracking to $x$, $x=276p+8$. And so the solution set is $$\left\{\left(276p+8, \frac{5^{276p+8}-55}{277}\right)\mid p\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$
